# Searching for a value in an Array of objects

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods

I have 2 additional classess apart from main (Person + Phonebook). I'm adding Person objects to an ArrayList which I've created in my Phonebook class.

Now I want to implent a method in my Phonebook class which will take in a string (The name of the person in the phonebook) and return the number if the person is in the phonebook. I've tried several things like trying to call the getName() method from the Person object.

This is what I have right now:

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name; 
    private String number;


    public Person(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;                      
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number; 
    }

    public void changeNumber(String newNumber) {
        this.number = newNumber; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " " + "number: " + getNumber(); 
    }

}
```

Phonebook class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Phonebook {
  private ArrayList<Person> person; 
    public Phonebook() {
        this.person = new ArrayList<Person>(); 
    }  


    public void add(String name, String number) {


    Person newPerson = new Person(name, number); 
    person.add(newPerson);

    }
    public void printAll() {
           for (Person prs : person) {
               System.out.println(prs);
           }
    }

    public String searchNumber(String name) {
        if (person.contains(name)) {
            return person.toString(); 
        }
            return "number not know"; 
    }




}
```

Comment: well, you can´t just compare a `Person` and a `String` and expect java to know where a logical equality would be ;)

Comment: You can use a Map instead of a List. This way you can search the person without iterating through the list.The key of the map would be the name of the person and the value the Person Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your person:

```
public boolean matchesName(String name) {
   return this.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```

What this method does is make both names lower case, to avoid Smith not matching to smith. Then it checks if the searchkey is contained within the persons name.
if so, it returns true. if not it returns false. 
So `smith` will match on `john smith` but also on `jake Smithsson`

and then in your search method

```
public String searchNumber(String name) {
     for (Person prs : person) {
          if(prs.matchesName(name)) {
            return prs.toString();
          }
     }
     return "number not known"; 
}
```

You need to iterate through the list to find them.

If you have less than 10.000 this is pretty fast. If you're going to add more names you need to start consider things like indexing or database storage.

But, this only returns one person.

Prefably you return all matches.

```
public List<Person> searchNumber(String name) {
     ArrayList<Person> matchlist = new ArrayList<Person>();
     for (Person prs : person) {
          if(prs.matchesName(name)) {
            matchlist.add(prs);
          }
     }
     return matchlist; 
}
```

Why not a map? You can modify the search functionality in this to your wishes.

Like, what if you have scandinavian names but people type in american searchqueries:

```
class AccentedNamePerson extends Person {
    private String normalised;
    private String normalisedName() {
       if(normalised != null) return normalised;
       normalised = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
       /** assuming input is in unicode. if ascii use .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""); **/
       normalised  = normalised.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
       return normalised;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean matchesName(String name) {
        String
        return this.normalisedName().toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is OK but using a Map as @Benat suggested is more efficient.

Comment: Hey great answer with a great explenation. Very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but with this solution you can do partial matches, and modify the .matchesName per person instance. Maybe you need special tweakings for scandanavian names, utf8, datasource polling, etc...